# javascript to print contents of only specific <div>

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have tried javascript `window.print()` It prints the full page content including the print button on the page.

Comment: [A List Apart][1] has a very good article about this. [1]:http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You require to create new style sheet print.css and set `CSS media=print`

for example :

```
<style media="screen">
  .noPrint{ display: block; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>

<style media="print">
  .noPrint{ display: none; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>
```

for more detail : [Print a doument with CSS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/Printing_with_CSS.aspx)

Comment: Thnx Pranay. I was looking for the same. +1

Answer (score 2):

Create an iframe and copy your text into it. then you can call the print-function of this, in the iframe embedded window

or

see: 
[**String.print()**](http://michael.josi.de/string-print/)