# How to use JavaScript to print the contents on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use the print() function to print the contents of a `<div class="pagecontent"></div>`

I know you can do something like `onClick="window.print()"` but this prints the entire window...I only want the contents of `.pagecontent` to be printed.

What's the easiest way I can go about doing this using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to print contents of only specific <div>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955237/javascript-to-print-contents-of-only-specific-div)

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071962/how-to-print-part-of-rendered-html-page-in-javascript ?

Comment: to see the similar question with answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way  is to define a stylesheet that applies for `@media=print`. It would basically have something like:

```
* { 
   display: none;  /* hide all elements when printing */
}

.pageContent {
   display: block; /* make any class="pageContent" elements visible while printing */
}
```

Of course, this would make the pageContent elements visible, but anything inside them would still be invisible from the `*` rule. You'll have to play with this and list only the top-level elements that should be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the contents of an element to an iframe and then print the iframe.

HTML --

```
<span>Print Just Me.</span> I'll be omitted.<br />
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>​
```

JS --

```
$('span').on('click', function () {
    $('#iframe').contents().find('body').html($(this).html());
    window.frames['iframe'].print();
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zaF3K/

You can also hide the iframe so this happens behind the scenes:

```
#iframe {
    display : none;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zaF3K/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is the jqprint jquery plugin, take a look

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint

Comment: OP said "without javascrsipt or jquery"

Comment: @MarcB "What's the easiest way I can go about doing this using JavaScript or jQuery?" directly from the post.  He said using javascript or jQuery

Comment: sigh... right. lemme just go prop my eyes open with a couple 2x4s.

Comment: In that case you have to generate a new page with only the content you  want to print. Since even opening a popup window and putting your content there to print, is "javascript")

Answer (score 1):

if you want to using javascript than try this

```
 window.printItn = function() {

                var printContent = document.getElementById('pagecontent');

                var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
                var uniqueName = new Date();
                var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();

    //  you should add all css refrence for your html. something like.

                var WinPrint= window.open(windowUrl,windowName,'left=300,top=300,right=500,bottom=500,width=1000,height=500');
                WinPrint.document.write('<'+'html'+'><head><link href="cssreference" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><'+'body style="background:none !important"'+'>');
                WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);

                WinPrint.document.write('<'+'/body'+'><'+'/html'+'>');
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                WinPrint.close();
                }
```

**See Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/mu8BG/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the div by using innerHTML and storing that as a string, then just print or log that piece by itself.

```
var string_to_print = $('#pagecontent').html();
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Using pure javascript you can't, but you can use `media print` CSS [type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)