# How can i apply CSS to print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, media

I am trying to print a div in one of my pages but i can't apply css when printing. Writing media="print" inside of the style tags doesn't work. What should i do?

```
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
body
{
font-size:medium;
color:Black;
font-size:14px;
}
input 
{
margin:0px;
font-size:14px;


}
.grid
{
border-color:Gray;
border-width:1px;

}
.alan
{
border-style:none;

}

.grid1
{
border-color:Gray;
border-width:1px;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: [media print CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: try this construction:
`<style type="text/css"> 
@media print
body {...}
... 
</style>`

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724163/how-to-use-javascript-to-print-the-contents-on-a-div/

Comment: @import url(somefile.css) print; try this

Answer (score 12):

Use the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
        body {
            /* styles */
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It still remains same with no css at print page.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also there is no guarantee that `Print Preview` will style the document; because it is at the discretion of the preview program, so actually try printing a page.

Comment: I am using Chrome and i tried to actually printing. But still css is not applied.

Answer (score 4):

There is many ways for that:

First: `<style type="text/css"media="print">`

Second: `<style type="text/css"media="screen">`

Third:

```
@media print 
 {
 body { margin: 0; background-image: none; font-size: 12pt; }
 }
```

Hope this is Helpful for you..

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in your original message will work fine.  It's just the *old school* way of doing things.

**One thing to note is that the browser will not apply all of your styles in the print mode.**  It picks and chooses which styles are print appropriate. I have also found that if you use a HTML 5 doctype it will give you slightly different results.

Here's a simple example similar to yours that you can try in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style media="print">
.hideForPrint { display:none; }
.anotherSTyle { font-family: Verdana; text-decoration:underline; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hideForPrint">Print This?</div>
<div class="anotherStyle">Another Style</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot from the print preview of Chrome (v19.0.1077.3 canary), which you mentioned your using to test this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [Jquery Print Element 1.2](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) plugin to print only the content of a div. 
This way, you don't need to set css display:none for all those elements you don't want to print.

I know it's not a straight answer on your question, but see it as a kind suggestion.

Example:

```
$('SelectorToPrint').printElement();
```

Here's my implementation using the classNameToAdd option:

```
function printDiv(divToPrint) {

   $('#' + divToPrint).printElement(
        {
            printBodyOptions:
            {
                classNameToAdd: 'printarea'

            }
        }
   );

}
```

Once you've added the plugin to your page you can call the above function when the users clicks the print button/link.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:printDiv('theIDofYourDiv')">Print part of the page</a>
```

You can download this plugin and find more documentation [here](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/).