# eliminate formatting changing when printing Reports in HTML format

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, printing

i have tried to get a report from mysql db and it was succeed. The required report is displayed in the first image.

but when printing total document, its going to be change the formatings as the 2 nd diagram. printed document formatings doesn't  satisfy  my requirements. so kindly tell me any solution to eliminate this.

am using javascript to print the document as follows 
    
                             Print

```
                    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840004/how-can-i-apply-css-to-print

Comment: Probably you have a separate CSS section for printing - `@media print` - you should look there if you'd like to change the formatting.