# Clear webpage after printing

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print the content of a particular DIV and after printing the DIV the webpage has to be fixed properly but its just displaying only the DIV I just printed and hides the actual webpage. Any guess what's wrong?

My code is

```
function printdiv(printpage)
{
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = newstr;
window.print();
window.close();
}
```

and

```
<img src="im/print.png" onClick="printdiv('mytabprint');" width="50" />
```

In the above code `mytabprint` is the DIV element which I want to print.

Comment: why don't you show/hide this with css media queries?

Comment: @DanielA.White - want to display all the website but want to display only that query.

Comment: @DanielA.White because what would you do to fix `<div>Don't print me!<div id="mytabprint">Print me!</div></div>`

Answer (score 3):

> Any guess what's wrong?

Yes, you're not "hiding" the other contents, you're actually replacing the whole page contents with your div:

```
document.body.innerHTML = newstr;
```

You can simply use a print stylesheet instead. For example, add this to your CSS:

```
@media print {
   /* 
   rules that only apply for printing 
   like hiding some content
   */
}
```

Or link a separate CSS for printing with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_css.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Comment: How will this work? It's printing my complete page. I need to print only a part of the webpage. i.e. I have to print only one DIV. Not, entire website.

Comment: You have to create css rules inside that block to hide anything you don't want to print (with `display: none`), and possibly reformat what you do want to print.

Comment: @Kerry See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955237/javascript-to-print-contents-of-only-specific-div